# WPF calendar deselects selected dates on LostFocus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have add a calendar control to my WPF project which looks like this;

```
<Calendar x:Name="DatesCalendar" SelectionMode="SingleRange" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

The idea is when a user selects a range of dates and clicks the search button I get entries from the database which are in the range. At the moment whenever the user clicks the search button the Calendar dates become deselected. I want the last dates selected to remain selected when the Calendar has lost focus.

Comment: Why not two two date time picker controls instead?

Comment: I think it looks neater selecting dates on calendar but I might have to resolute to using time picker controls instead if the calendar doesn't work.

Comment: Date time pickers show a popular calendar. So you loose no functionality. In one of my apps, not WPF, I actually have two calendars. One for start and one for end dates.

Comment: Could you select a range with 1 DateTimePicker control? I mean naturally the dates should remain selected in calendar after being selected right?

Comment: Do you need to bind your calendar to a variable?

Comment: If that's possible. Yes. Given that I get a range of selected dates. The only way I see solving this is to watch the `SelectedDatesChanged` event and copy the selected dates somewhere then when LostFocus occurs I select the dates again programmatically. But I don't think that's very practical.

Answer (score 0):

I read about a possible answer to this issue [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/6af18675-c570-49fa-b489-7423305d472e/calendar-selecteddates-to-bind-to-viewmodel?forum=silverlightarchieve). For the sake of completeness I replicate the information provided there:

`Calendar.SelectedDates` is a **Readonly Property**. Therefore you can't set `Binding` to it in the `XAML`.

However, you can do it this way:

1) Add `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` to your **Project References**

2) Add `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll` to your **Project References**

3) Add the following `namespace` prefix to your **XAML**:

```
`xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`
`xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"`
```

4) **XAML**:

```
<sdk:Calendar Name="Cal" SelectionMode="MultipleRange" >
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDatesChanged">
             <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDates, ElementName=Cal}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</sdk:Calendar>`
```

5) **ViewModel**:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
       this.SelectionCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.SelectionChanges );
    }

    public ICommand SelectionCommand { get; private set; }

    private void SelectionChanges(object sender)
    {
             SelectedDatesCollection dates = sender as SelectedDatesCollection;
    } 
}
```

I have not tested this myself. Does it help you? There is more information in the link at the top of this answer.